# Data Handling in a Cucumber Framework with 5000 scenarios. QAF implementation is Out of Scope

Tags: selenium, cucumber, bdd, cucumber-java

I am going to work on a new project where we have 5000 test cases/scenarios. Each scenario has coming functions like login, Amount Transfer, etc. Therefore each scenario will have certain data. So, in case 5000 scenarios, I feel it will very difficult to handle the data. Because even if the password of the Login user gets changed, then I need to update the Password 5000 times in all the scenarios from different feature files. This goes against the idea of Automation where we are targeting to reduce the manual effort. So I am asking here if anyone has any idea/workarounds to handle such situations I hope there should be. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Typically speaking you would create a new user for each test and discard it at the end of the test.

You should also not describe all the details of the users that are created. These often are not relevant to the test and merely [incidental details](https://cucumber.io/blog/bdd/cucumber-antipatterns-part-one/#incidentaldetails). Rather you would use a template and only describe the changes made to this template in the feature file. If for auditing reasons you have to describe this template, you can write a scenario that tests your template.

Comment: Creating a new user for each test case and repeat the activity for 5000 times is not feasible. In my case, the client will share a set of users to test the 5000 test cases/scenarios. Therefore I am looking for a solution a where the data can be managed in a single data file and all the scenarios can fetch the respective data from there.

Comment: It sounds like you are in a situation that is not conductive to automation. However you can still read the details from file in the implementation of a step definition rather then put them in the feature file.

Comment: The situation can be handled very well in UFT or in KDF in selenium, but yes I am in a situation where the regression should be run after every sprint in the BDD framework.

Comment: The tool doesn't matter. If you can't create the data the test needs as part of the test, then the environment is not conductive to test automation. That you are able to automate something doesn't mean that you won't suffer all the downsides of using fixed data. You'll have to babysit your tests, removing the benefits of automation.

Comment: I don't know but in KDF, we can change the data in one go, because the keywords and data can be stored in different sheets, hence no need to put more effort into data management. I hope other guys also faced the similar issues as me and I right get help from them.

Comment: I believe I addressed that. Don't put the user details in the feature file. Read them from your data file in a step definition implementation. That you need to do data management at all however is exactly what makes for poor automation. You can try and make it work now but then you'll be back looking at the same root cause again.